# Seleccionar múltiples IDs para operar con resultados

Tags: php, mysql

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me tome todos los códigos del producto para que me inserte en la tabla `det_mat_prima`?

Adjunto fotos de mis tablas y datos:

[image: Imagen 1]
[image: Imagen 2]
[image: Imagen 3]
[image: Imagen 4]

Con este código solo me toma el último código del producto, es decir, si en la orden existen 3 productos solo me toma el código del último producto y debería de tomar los 3 para sumar las cantidades:

```html
        if ($_GET['act'] == 'insert') {
        if (isset($_POST['Guardar'])) {
            $codigo = $_POST['mp_cod'];
            $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
            $emp_cod = $_POST['emp_cod'];
            $estado = 'ACTIVO';
            $suc_cod = $_SESSION['suc_cod'];
            $usu_cod = $_SESSION['usu_cod'];
            $ord_cod = $_POST['ord_cod'];

            //insertar
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO  pedido_mp (mp_cod, emp_cod, mp_fecha, mp_estado,
                suc_cod, usu_cod,ord_cod) VALUES ($codigo, '$emp_cod', '$fecha', '$estado', $suc_cod, $usu_cod,$ord_cod)")
                or die('Error' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

            //Insertar detalle de presupuesto 
            $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM det_orden WHERE ord_cod=$ord_cod");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $codigo_producto = $row['prod_cod'];
                $cantidad_orden = $row['deto_cant'];
                
        }

            //Insertar detalle de presupuesto 
            $formula = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM det_formula WHERE prod_cod='$codigo_producto'");
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($formula)) { 
                $materia_p = $data['mat_cod']; 
                $cantidad_mp = $data['detfor_cant']; 
                $cantidad = $cantidad_orden * $cantidad_mp;  
               
                    $insert_detalle = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO det_mat_prima (mat_cod, mp_cod, 
                    detmat_cant) VALUES ('$materia_p', '$codigo', '$cantidad')")
                        or die('Error' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
                
            }



            if ($insert_detalle) {
                header("Location: ../../main.php?module=pedido_mp&alert=1");
            } else {
                header("Location: ../../main.php?module=pedido_mp&alert=4");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola xmaname, por favor revisa de nuevo el [tour] y lee sobre [ask]. Es muy importante que las preguntas estén estructuradas correctamente para que el resto de usuarios pueda ayudarte más fácilmente: añade un título descriptivo (p.e. no algo como "necesito ayuda"), añade detalles sobre lo que quieres hacer y los problemas que estás encontrando, y añade la información sobre datos y código en formato texto en lugar de como imágenes (porque hay gente que no puede ver las imágenes por diferentes motivos.) ¡Un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, trataré de ser más concreto! Saludos,